# $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ isn't direct product of two non-trivial groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I know that this has been posted before. I would like to know whether my argument is correct or not. I am presenting a new argument, so this question shouldn't be marked as duplicate.

> Suppose that $Q \cong H \times K$ such that neither H or K is trivial. This is achieved through isomorphism $\psi : H \times K \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$.   I claim that kernel $\psi = H\times \{0\}$. That is, if we assume that H is non-trivial.

**Proof**

$$\small\frac{p_{(h,k)}}{q_{(h,k)}} = \psi((h,k) = \psi( (h,0) + (0,k) ) = \psi((h,0)) + \psi((0,k)) = \frac{p_{(h,0)}}{q_{(h,0)}} + \frac{p_{(0,k)}}{q_{(0,k)}} = \frac{p_{(h,0)}q_{(0,k)} + p_{(0,k)}q_{(h,0)}}
{q_{(h,0)}q_{(0,k)}} = 0$$

$p_{(h,k)} = p_{(h,0)}q_{(0,k)} + p_{(0,k)}q_{(h,0)} = 0$. This gives us
$p_{(h,0)}q_{(0,k)} = -p_{(0,k)}q_{(h,0)}$. We can choose k such that $p_{(0,k)} = 0$. Therefore $p_{(h,0)}q_{(0,k)} = 0$ implies that $p_{(h,0)} = 0$. Therefore $H\times \{0\} \subset \operatorname{ker}(\psi)$ giving us a contradiction that $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: See Najib Idrissi's answer that the kernel is $0\times H$.

Comment: Why is my answer marked as duplicate I am presenting new argument.

Comment: Why is your argument new? This is exactly the answer at the duplicate that the kernel is $0\times H$, so that the map cannot be an isomorphism to the direct product.

Comment: The argument presented in the question was based on orders of element.